# How to find if two rows are similar to each other?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to see if two rows are similar to each other in SQL, and how many of such exist?

```
select columna,columnb from table1 
having columna like columnb
```

Something like that? A matching of '%columnb%' would work perfectly, because I know that columnb is always a "subset" of columna.

```
| columna        | columnb      |
---------------------------------
| www.reddit.com | reddit       | 
| www.cnn.com    | bbc          |
| www.yahoo.com  | yahoo        |
```

Ideally I'd like a result like this.

```
| count(*)       | state        |
---------------------------------
| 2              | similar      | 
| 0              | notsimilar   |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `"www.google.com"` and `"www.google.us"`? What if 1-2 letters are different or just missing? What if one domain is an alias for another? That is: you need to define what is _similarity_ in your context

Comment: Similarity is just that columnb is contained in columna. So if columnb has "google" then it should match www.google.com and www.google.us, but not goog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with LIKE.  It looks like this:

```
SELECT State, COUNT(State)
FROM
(
SELECT varcol1, varcol2,
CASE WHEN varcol1 LIKE CONCAT('%',varcol2,'%') THEN 'similar'
ELSE 'not similar' END AS State
FROM test.test) a
GROUP BY State;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*),state
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN LOCATE(columnB,ColumnA)<>0 THEN 'notsimilar' 
                 ELSE 'similar' END as state
FROM tableName
) as Z
GROUP BY state
```

You can use [**LOCATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function to check whether **columnB** value lies in **columnA**